# How to keep section number from being reset with new chapter (ref: Sokolnikoff)

Tags: sectioning

I like the way the author Igor Sokolnikoff numbers his sections and equations, and would like to mimic this style in my own book. The section number is never reset. For example chapter one ends with section 17, and chapter two begins with section 18. Also equations are numbered according to section, not chapter, as (17.1), (17.2), etc.

I am using MikTex, pdflatex
Thank You!

[image: Sokolnikoff - Contents]

[image: Sokolnikoff - Chapter/Equations]

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  the section counter is usually reset in the document class, so what would be needed is to patch the document class to remove that setting.  for doing that, we would need to know what document class you intend to use.

Comment: "...in my own book" = \documentclass{book}

Comment: Werner - Could you provide me a link to this already existing question? I looked for it, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: the link is in the "closed as duplicate" line.  however, the information you want is pretty far down, buried in the answer.  i'm leaving now, but if i can connect from home later, i'll try to retrieve it and post it here, for convenience.

Comment: The following worked:

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

Thanks!